# Combining Colours and Alphas in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

I have been trying to find a way of MovieClip(1) (set to blue - 50% alpha) being moved over MovieClip(2) (set to red - 50% alpha) and afterward MovieClip(1) taking on the colour value that is equal to the mix of the initial colours of MovieClip(1) and MovieClip(2) (maintaining 50% alpha levels).

I am stuck - brain freeze and I can't seem to find a solution that gets me anywhere close!

Anyone have any ideas for a solution?

Providing me some headway would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried so far? where is code?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this snippet

http://www.actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/37-mixing-colors-add-10-percent-of-one-color-to-another-actionscript-30-as3-

You can tweak that a bit to fit your needs, like setting both the .1 and .9 in the rgb3 section to .5

Answer (score 1):

What you want is yourMC.transform.colorTransform

Here is some [headway](http://www.flashandmath.com/basic/colors/) that will explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Both MovieClip objects must have a color defined by their `colorTransform` property.

```as3
var ctf :ColorTransform = mc1.transform.colorTransform;
    ctf.color = color;            
mc1.transform.colorTransform = ctf;
```

Then combine the two `ColorTransform` objects into a new one, by adding to each property of the `ColorTransform` object of the first MovieClip the difference with the same property of the second MovieClip, divided by 2.

```as3
var ctf1 :ColorTransform = mc1.transform.colorTransform,
    ctf2 :ColorTransform = mc2.transform.colorTransform;        

var props :Array = ["redOffset", "redMultiplier", "greenOffset", "greenMultiplier", "blueOffset", "blueMultiplier"];
for each(var p :String in props)
    ctf1[p] += (ctf2[p] - ctf1[p]) * a;

mc1.transform.colorTransform = ctf1;
```

Here is a code snippet that will explain by itself: http://wonderfl.net/c/fQ1i